# How to replace html using dreamweaver's "find and replace"?

Tags: find-and-replace, dreamweaver

I want to do find and replace for example . In dreamweaver's find and replace

`<p><strong>Business Development</strong></p>`

into

`<h4>Business Development</h4>`

I have to change in lots of files.

I'm trying this to type it in search and replace, but it's not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply use Dreamweaver's Regex Replace function. (Ctrl-F and check "Use Regular Expression")

Find:

`<p><strong>(.*)</strong></p>`

Replace:

`<h4>$1</h4>`

Comment: ok will try this.

Comment: great working thanks. but why dreaweaver's non-regex option not working

Answer (score 1):

[This may help you.](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/dreamweaver-tip-search-replace-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

how about [reading the manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Dreamweaver/10.0_Using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7cc7a.html)? it has all the answers, such as "Search for a specific tag, Containing ...", "Use Regular Expressions", and "Search in Entire Current Local Site".

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is "Read The Friendly Manual", usually abbreviated "RTFM."  There may be other interpretations of the acronym.

Comment: i know the phrase - but refrained from using it. because there may be other interpretations :)

Answer (score 0):

I saw the answer on your Stack Overflow question, however, I do this sort of thing all the time in Dreamweaver.

Simply change the `Search` field to `Source Code` and then it should be able to do it easily if you type your two statements in.

[image]

Comment: i'm not asking about simple find and replace see my question i just given a example Text inside Tag can be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the -1... You do exactly what I said, change to Source Code and simply put <p><strong>Business Development</strong></p> in to find, and replace with <h4>Business Development</h4>... It does work.

Comment: still getting wrong

Comment: Well then - Phrase your question better then before giving a -1! You said replace x with y, doing what I said does that... I use it pretty much on a daily basis.... Have you actually tried it?

Comment: I don't want to replace text inside tag i want to change tags only see here <p><strong>Business Development</strong></p>

Comment: Exactly... So, as I said, if I want to change <test>blabla<test> to <argh>blabla<argh> I would put both in the search, and it would find and replace. Or, simply put "test" and "argh" in the find/replace, either way, it solves what you asked for in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The Dreamweaver command you're looking for is "change tag" which is [dreamweaver cc search and replace interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCmLy.png)